# How to kill/stop a powershell process on no output for some period of time

Tags: powershell

Creating  processes using powershell start-process command , which will executes the processes sequentially and output will be displayed in console. below is the code snippet:

```
foreach($module in $selectedModules){
            $filepath = $basePath + $module
            Start-Process -FilePath $filepath -ArgumentList $cmdArgs  -Wait -NoNewWindow
    }
```

If one process stuck, need to kill it so that next iteration process will start.If console output not updated for specified time range say 15 minutes, we can consider that process got hang and stop it. so that next process will begin.Tried with wait-process, but it needs predefined timeout value in place.  any better way to find out stuck process ? or need to time with no output.

Comment: If you want help with your code, then... Post it in your question. Also show us how you run that code, for how long, what the purpose is etc.

Comment: Do you need to consume or display the output? Or just keep track of whether anything is being output at all?

Comment: please see  updated question description with sample code.